# MariaDB Sequence

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, mariadb

We have created a MaraDB sequence starting with 7.000.000, 'increment' is 50, 'cache_size' is 1.000 per default:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE order_SEQ START WITH 7000000 INCREMENT BY 50 MINVALUE=7000000;
```

Our Entity has the following Annotations:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) 
private long id;
```

When starting the database and creating an entry in the order table, MariaDB loads the next sequence and increases the value by 50.000. So "next_not_cached_value" is set to 7.050.000. So far so good.

By inserting a new row in the order table the next id is 7.049.951.

Does anyone know why this happens. My expectation was that it will start with 7.050.001. Could this be an issue?

Example of table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `genDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `genUser` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `modDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `modUser` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `userId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Message_IDX_ID` (`id`),
  KEY `Message_IDX_Sent` (`sent`),
  KEY `Message_IDX_UserId` (`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Me_FK_User` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: show how the order table is using the sequence (e.g. output of `show create table order`)

Comment: @ysth I have added in the first post the table declaration

Comment: oh, so your framework is using the sequence, not mariadb.  seems like it may not know how to use a mariadb sequence, is there a way to tell what requests it is doing?

Comment: Yes, we are using Hibernate (Spring Boot) to determine the next sequence.